# max number of child nodes navigable with xPath in htm lAgility pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML agility pack to remove bad html in database entries. I am trying to delete the nodes by using `SelectSingleNode(xpath).Remove();`. this is throwing an error

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'The xpath query is too complex.

is there a maximum number of nodes you can navigate through when using xPath, or is there another reason this error is occuring? I reduced the number of nodes in a test and xPath worked okay, below is the xpath that is throwing this exception. (it is messy)

---

```
/p[1]/span[1]/span[1]/strong[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/strong[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/strong[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/strong[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]/span[1]/b[1]/b[1]
```

---

---

***Note:*** The reason for wanting to do this is because I am on placement bug fixing. there is html entries stored in the db that got stuffed with unwanted html due to a rad editor bug that was left unnoticed until it broke the rad editor when loading reports. I need to keep the styling which is stored in html tags so I can't delete all the HTML.

Comment: If you get that error then apparently there is a maximum.. Is there no element along the way have an id you can search by?..

Comment: it is for thousands of records so I can't dynamically find any (or at least I don't think I can), i wrote two methods to try reduce the bad html, one removing all tags with no inner text by looping through all the child tags and the other doing a similar thing to remove tags of the same type with the same inner text and style. It resolved the problem for the other bad records where this was occurring but its only reducing this current html by 1500 characters and the xpath is still extremely complex.

Comment: the html is also a mess which is why the first two methods don't work as intended. I will edit and attach the method I am using to try remove tags by the xpath

Answer (score 1):

I did some more testing on this, It seems like I can not go more that 511 elements deep. this is for an XPath navigating to a node with no expressions other than the path in the xPath